zref substitutes for some crossreftools commands?
I'd like to switch from cleveref and crossreftools to zref-based cross-referencing — including with zref-clever and zref-vario — (with hyperref, too), .
[The reason is: (i) to allow compatibility with the latex3 tagging project; and (ii) unease with the last update to crossreftools being 2020.]
How might one obtain equivalents of the following crossreftools commands?

\crtcrefcountervalue
\crtrefanchor
\crtrefname

Currently, I use those three in a (very complicated) preamble that includes macros such as these:
\newcommand{\crefex}[2]{\hyperref[#2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1}~(\crtcrefcountervalue{#2})}}

\newcommand{\crefthmname}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}


I'm not really well acquainted with crossreftools, but what you mention you use seems to be covered easily with standard commands from zref/zref-clever.
With zref-clever enabled, the default list of properties includes the following:
\zref@newlabel{sec:label}{\default{1}\page{1}\abspage{1}\zc@counter{section}\thecounter{1}\zc@type{section}\zc@cntval{1}\zc@pgval{1}\zc@enclval{}\zc@pgfmt{1}\anchor{section.1}}

Some of them provided by zref, other added by zref-clever (zc@ prefix). So:

\crtcrefcountervalue -> \zref@extractdefault{label}{zc@cntval}{0} (though, if your use case for this is your \crefex, I suspect there is some misunderstanding. This piece of data is stored by cleveref and zref-clever for the purposes of sorting the labels, never typesetting.)
\crtrefanchor -> \zref@extract{label}{anchor}
\crtrefname -> \zref@extract{label}{title}

(For the title property, you need to load zref-title too.)
From your custom macros a MWE would be welcome to understand desired output etc., but:

\namecref -> \zcref[noref]
\labelcref -> \zcref[noname]

And the rest is already covered. But you probably have better ways of doing things. For example, your whole \crefthmname sounds like just \zcref[noname,ref=title]{label}. (And isn't \namecref{#1}~\labelcref*{#1} just \cref*{#1}?)
